# How does PDO::prepare() generates a PDOStatement object?

Tags: php, mysql, prepare, pdo

How is the *readonly* `$queryString` property being set inside PDOStatement class by the `PDO::prepare()` execution?

Given the class definition, I don't see any functions which would set that query. Does that mean PDOStatement class can't be used if it's not generated by the PDO class instance through `PDO::prepare()` function?

Comment: It doesn't need to expose any setter methods. A `PDOStatement` is instantiated and populated PDO-internally. While you could create one manually, it wouldn't be connected to anything or be useable elsewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDOstatement is created internally, by means of C code. And of course C code can set any properties directly.

And yes, you cannot use PDOStatement class (for anything useful) if it's not generated by the PDO class instance through `PDO::prepare()` (or `query()`).

However, you can redeclare and tell PDO to use it instead of standard one using code like this

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['myPDOStatement', [$pdo]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php#pdostatement.intro):

> Introduction
>
> ---
>
> [The PDOStatement class] Represents a prepared statement and, after the statement is executed, an associated result set.

This looks like it has to be created by `PDO::prepare()`.

But is this a problem? I cannot say that I came across a situation where I want to create an PDOStatement object by hand.

Comment: It's not a problem at all. I was just curious in the flow of object creation without exposure of a function which would set the query string to create the PDOStatement object. I never had to create a PDOStatement object by hand either.